# math in awk - unexpected formatting of floating-point numbers - loss of precision

Tags: awk

I am trying to do some simple math in awk

```
user@lab-client:~$ awk '{ram=(1.8 * 1024) * 1024; print ram}'

1.88744e+06
```

So I assume this means that this number is too large to be stored in variable "ram"

The total number is: 1887436.8

Lets try to store that number in the variable

```
user@lab-client:~$ awk '{ram=1887436.8; print ram}'

1.88744e+06
```

Same again. But what if we get rid of the "."?

```
user@lab-client:~$ awk '{ram=18874368; print ram}'

18874368
```

Further tests show that when the dot is in the number, it cannot be longer than 6 digits

```
user@lab-client:~$ awk '{ram=188743.68; print ram}'

188744
```

So its not a too large number, it is the dot that messes things up. How can I get around this?

Comment: Thanks! Turns out my question was indeed a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can control the number of decimal points with printf, eventually though the numbers won't be significant due to floating point representation

for example

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=5;i<20;i++) printf "%."i"f\n", 1./3}'

0.33333
0.333333
0.3333333
0.33333333
0.333333333
0.3333333333
0.33333333333
0.333333333333
0.3333333333333
0.33333333333333
0.333333333333333
0.3333333333333333
0.33333333333333331
0.333333333333333315
0.3333333333333333148
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [karakfa's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181743/45375):

In addition to *explicit* number formatting with `printf` and `sprintf`, **you can also change `awk`'s *default* floating-point number formatting**, via **built-in variable `OFMT`**.
Note that it does *not* apply to *integers*.

**`OFMT` defaults to `%.6g`**, which means that any floating-point number is rounded to 6 significant digits and for exponents starting with 7 is represented in scientific notation.

Calculation result `1887436.8` - which has *8* significant digits - is therefore represented as `1.88744e+06`, i.e., in scientific notation with 6 significant digits.

The following example sets `OFMT` to `%1.f` in order to output all floating-point numbers with 1 decimal place by default:

```
$ awk -v OFMT='%.1f' 'BEGIN {ram=(1.8 * 1024) * 1024; print ram}'
1887436.8
```

Note, however, that `OFMT` does *not* apply in the following scenarios:

- If the floating-point number is used in a *string concatenation*:

  ```
  $ awk -v OFMT='%.1f' 'BEGIN { print "result: " 1 / 3 }'
  result: 0.333333

  # Workaround: Use `sprintf()` with OFMT
  awk -v OFMT='%.1f' 'BEGIN { print "result: " sprintf(OFMT, 1 / 3) }'
  result: 0.3
  ```
- If a literal can be *parsed* as an *integer* - even if it *looks* like a floating-point number:

  ```
  $ awk -v OFMT='%.1f' 'BEGIN { print 1.000 }'
  1
  ```

*Caveat*: There are many subtleties around number conversion and formatting in `awk`, not least because of the limited precision of floating-point numbers (which in `awk` are always of the ISO C *double* type).